# Как посчитать арифметическое выражение, записанное в префиксной форме (с использованием стека)

Tags: python, стек

Я не силен в питоне, как и в принципе в программировании, но у меня были идеи, что подаваемый список нужно перевернуть, чтобы потом с ним можно было нормально работать в стеке. Как - не знаю. За этим и обращаюсь. Изначально давался такой код для решения арифметического выражения в постфиксной форме:
`

```
data=input().split()
stack=[]
bool=True
for x in data:
    if x in "+-*/":
        if len(stack)<2:
            print("Ошибка: в стеке меньше двух элементов")
            bool=False
            break
        op2=int(stack.pop())
        op1=int(stack.pop())
        if x=="+":
            res=op1+op2
        elif x=="-":
            res=op1-op2
        elif x=="*":
            res=op1*op2
        elif x=="/":
            res=op1//op2
        else:
            stack.append(res)
    else:
        stack.append(x)
if len(stack)==1:
    print(stack[0])
elif bool:
    print("Ошибка: выражение было записано не верно")
```

`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Пример нерабочий. Откуда он?

Comment: В примере операция `stack.append(res)` должна исполняться всегда, `else:` перед ней надо удалить